# jQuery Textbox Whole Number Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, textbox

I have the script below, which I use to validate input to validate a textbox for no text, and it also usefully doubles to only allow a number between 0 and 10 with up to 3 decimal places.

```
$('.sourceValidation').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^(([0-9]|10)(\.\d{1,3})?)?$/)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '').substring(0,5);}})
```

I am not entirely sure of this code, but how do I rework it so that it will validate an input between 0 and 99 (whole numbers only), no text, no decimal points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.sourceValidation').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^([0-9]{0,2})$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').substring(0,2);
    }
});
```

The key part is to change the regex from

```
/^(([0-9]|10)(\.\d{1,3})?)?$/
```

to

```
/^([0-9]{0,2})$/
```

..which is a regex which will allow 0, 1 or 2 digits. It will however allow leading zeroes eg `01`, `09` - or even `00`. I don't know if this is acceptable in your situation.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2W2E/1/)

The `replace` function is saying `[^0-9]/g` - which means - replace anything that is not (`^`) a digit (`0-9`) and do it through the whole string (`g` - global). It is then trimming it to 2 characters max (`substring(0,2)`).

Comment: I've created this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HCGGJ/ - you code will not work for me?

Comment: @DustinCook Sorry - I didn't change the alter function also - see my update and fiddle

Comment: With these regex questions everyone goes crazy trying to get their answer in first (including me :) )

Comment: Read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)! And never ever forget any of it!

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you need to accept only 0 to 99 without anything else is

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

This means : Accept digits from '0' to '9', 1 or 2 times.

Note that your code does not contain any jquery, this seems to be pure javascript. <-- Edit : this I take back. My bad.

Comment: He is binding the event using jQuery's `keyup`

Comment: Don't apologise to me, apologise to John Resig! He'll be absolutely infuriated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$|^99$
```

U Can Teast It [Link](http://regex101.com/r/yW4wF4)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the working version of jquery below

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/jQmR3/][1]
```

This allows users to type numbers only
        if ($.inArray(charpressed, alpha) > -1) {
            return false;
        }
You can add what characters you need to allow in the array there